# XPS - Printing documents with images

Tags: c#, wpf, xps

I've asked a similar question in the past but had no joy since then to solve my problem.  I'm no expert with Xps documents, but managed to nail down my problem to this...

The following examples takes a `DocumentPaginator` argument and simply prints the document.
The first example works, the second one doesn't not print the images embedded in the document.

```
// this works

XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);
xpsDocumentWriter.Write(document);  // where document is a DocumentPaginator

// this doesn't work (it prints but no images)

// create new doc
XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.NotCompressed, "pack://TempTemporaryPackageUri.xps");

// create writer for new doc
XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

// write document
writer.Write(document, printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket);

// create writer for print job
XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue);

// i think it's here where the resources are being lost 

// write document
xpsDocumentWriter.Write(doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence());
```

The reason why I need to create a new document is because I need to manipuate the XpsDocument once it's been paginated.

Can anybody point me in the right direction with regards to being able to copy the resources from one doc to another?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: I think you're still chasing down the wrong path. Once you've created your paginated XPS document, modify that document directly rather than try to copy it.

Comment: How do you then print the xpsdocument to the print queue. It seems when I create a new doc from the getfixeddocumentsequence it loses the resources - or leaves them in orig doc. I must be missing something simple

Comment: [PrintQueue.AddJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553644.aspx) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code as given on the link below. It is working for converting to XPS and PDF formats.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: thanks for reply anshul, but i'm trying to create an XpsDoc from an exisiting doc but adding an additional visual to each page. I'm not using Word or PDF. thanks though.

Comment: ok. but in that code the difference between your requirement and example is only changing the format to wdExportFormatXPS and also if you want to add some data just write the doc fiel as you want to by FileStreamer and then convert it.